# if else condition based update status in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, if-statement, mongodb-query

not working this any other solution..

```
findOneAndUpdate( {"_id": ObjectId("5714ce0a4514ef3ef68677fd")}, $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$isRequired", true ] }, then: { "status": "Done" }, else: { { "status": "Approved" } } )
```

same collection status update based on isRequire is true or false.

Comment: Hi! welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide us more details on what the problem is, what you've tried and maybe a litlte more context with your code? Please check out [How do i ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help out your fellow SO'ers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is your query has a bad syntax, you are missing `{}` after que query object.

An update query is composed by: `update({query}, {update})` and you have write: `update( {query}, update)`.

Also, you can't use [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) into an update query because is an aggregate stage but since Mongo 4.2, mongo allows aggregation stages ([reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#db.collection.update)) so you can do this query:

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "5714ce0a4514ef3ef68677fd"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "status": {
        "$cond": {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$isRequired",
              true
            ]
          },
          then: "Done",
          else: "Approved"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X2RgqJuu_Af) with false value and [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hCVzT3qVM5J) with true